# Set button and imageview in gridview and how to set each of them listener

Tags: java, android, button, gridview

Hi guys I need your help. I want to set listner imageview and button in gridview and when I click to imageview app should show dialog with image and when I click to button app should do something.

like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljlcP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Custom Adapter for your GridView with Custom UI with ImageView and Button, and then inside the getVieew(){} you need to make click listener for Image and button, and there you can do your action with the help of position with your array list.

here I am posting demo adapter for your reference:

**here you can change TextView to Button.**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String [] result;
    Context context;
 int [] imageId;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
         holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

         rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

ref:-https://caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html